# Search pattern containing forward slash using AWK

Tags: awk

In AWK, is there a way to match pattern containing forward slash `/` without actually escaping it?

```
awk '$1~/pattern/' file
```

The above command works fine as long as there isn't any `/` in the pattern.

I am looking for something similar to what's available in [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) for using different separators in search and replace syntax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
awk '$0~v' v="patt/ern"
```

### Explanation

**N.B.:** extracted from comments, so upvote them too!

In `awk` **dynamic regex** and **regex constant** are not exactly same. The example in OP's question was *regex constant* you turned it into *dynamic regex* (see. [Using Dynamic Regexps](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html#SEC32)).

Comment: better add some description that in awk `dynamic regex` and `regex constant` are not exactly same. The example in OP's question was `regex constant` you turned it into `dynamic regex`

Comment: @Kent I am not what's the difference between `regex constant` and `regex constant` but somehow this works for my requirement.

Comment: @jkshah simply speak, `$0~/pattern/`  is not exactly same as `$0~"pattern"`, it depends on the pattern. Your current pattern may work. but you should use it with caution. see here: http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html#SEC32

Comment: @Kent Thanks for the reference. Now I get it. Since my patterns are almost constant strings coming from some map file, this should work fine. I was in impression that only `//` works. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

This may be OK for you:

```
kent$ echo "///aaa"|awk '/[/]/'
///aaa
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but pattern may not be as simple as `/`. It may be `a/b` and since it may be coming from another file, I don't prefer any modification and want to put pattern as is. I hope it's clear.

Comment: @jkshah what I meant is, you don't have to escape `/`, you could use char-class. if your pattern needs `foo/bar/blah`, you just `foo[/]bar[/]blah`

Comment: I got you. you are suggesting `[/]` in place of `\/` but what I would like to have is not altering regex pattern. It's comping from some map file and I am planning to store it in array and use it as match patterm

Comment: +1 for alternate option for escaping. But I would accept other ans.

Comment: @jkshah thanks, it is fine. point is your problem gets solved. :)