# How to escape Fish shell variable to use as awk pattern?

Tags: awk, docker, fish

I'm writing a function to list my latest images from a given docker repository:

```
function docker-latest
      set repo $argv[1]
      docker images | awk "/$repo/ && /latest/{print $1}"
  end
```

### Works fine…

Here is the `docker images` output

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
coaxisopt_daemon                                 latest              86bd3d602074        17 hours ago        830.7 MB
coaxisopt_daemon                                 v1.0.13             86bd3d602074        17 hours ago        830.7 MB
docker.site.fr:5000/coaxis/coaxisopt_daemon     latest              86bd3d602074        17 hours ago        830.7 MB
<none>                                           <none>              da0e5b0fc2a1        17 hours ago        830.7 MB
docker.site.fr:5000/coaxis/coaxisopt_daemon     <none>              9c0175d7d397        18 hours ago        830.7 MB
…
```

Here is my output as expected:

```
$ docker-latest coaxis
coaxisopt_daemon                                 latest              86bd3d602074        17 hours ago        830.7 MB
docker.akema.fr:5000/coaxis/coaxisopt_daemon     latest              86bd3d602074        17 hours ago        830.7 MB
```

### Until

However, when I put some `/` (slash) character in the end of my string to filter on pushed images:

```
$ docker-latest coaxis/
awk: cmd. line:1: /coaxis// && /latest/{print }
awk: cmd. line:1:           ^ syntax error
```

### Question

How do I escape the `repo` variable so I used it safely in `awk` pattern?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789643/search-pattern-containing-forward-slash-using-awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

```
docker images | awk -v repo="$repo"  '$1 ~ repo && $2 == "latest" {print $1}'
```

**Details:** the trick is to pass the `$repo` through the `awk`'s variable `repo` and escape `$1`.

Comment: Same error, could you explain what you try to achieve? To me you're matching 1st field (`$1`) against the `$repo` variable.

Comment: The trick is to pass the `$repo` through the awk variable `v`

Comment: Cant you use single quotes to delimit scripts in "Fish" so you don't have to go through escaping hell? (I've never heard of Fish so I've no idea).

Comment: okay... the "fish" is hopefully gone (i've never heard of him as well)...

Answer (score 0):

### Dirty solution

Use `sed`:

```
echo "coaxis/" | sed 's!/!\\\/!g'
```

Dirty cause it's not really generic.

### Full function

```
function docker-latest
      set repo (echo "$argv[1]" | sed 's!/!\\\/!g')
      docker images | awk "/$repo/ && /latest/{print $1}"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `sed`, then fully replace `awk` by `sed`. For this case it will be clearer & faster (not always the case with sed...)

`sed` allows to change the separator to anything after `s` command. I chose `#`.

```
sed -n "s#\([^ ]*${repo}[^ ]*\) \+latest.*#\1#p"
```

`-n` suppresses output, and `p` command prints only if match.

(If you have problems with `#`, you can choose anything, like `%`, or anything unlikely to happen in your expression)

Comment: I don't want to use `sed` in particular as it syntax is particularly unreadable and hard to maintain.