# Extract data from data files

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have 31 files and I'd like to extract specific data from them and to write it into one text file or to edit in the same file. Example of a file as follow :

[Please download 'codg0010.18i.Z' file](ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex/2018/001/)

Data as follow:

```
   2018     1     1     0     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
   ...
   45.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   59   63   69   76   83   90   96  100  100   93   81   68   55   46   39   34
   31   29   28   28   26   25   24   26   32   40   48   54   56   54   50   46
   43   42   42   44   46   48   51   54   57   59   59   58   55   51   48   47
   48   50   53   56   58   61   63   65   66   66   65   65   66   68   72   76
   82   86   88   87   81   72   64   59   59
    42.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   63   67   74   80   88   97  107  115  116  109   95   79   64   53   45   40
   37   36   36   38   39   39   40   43   48   54   60   63   62   59   54   50
   47   45   45   46   47   49   51   54   57   60   60   59   57   54   53   54
   56   60   62   64   65   67   69   72   74   74   74   73   72   72   74   77
   82   86   90   89   84   77   68   63   63
    40.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   71   75   80   84   90  100  112  123  127  122  108   91   75   64   56   50
   46   45   47   51   54   57   59   61   65   70   72   72   69   64   58   53
   50   48   47   46   46   47   49   52   56   59   61   61   59   58   58   60
   63   66   68   68   68   70   73   77   80   82   82   81   80   79   79   81
   84   89   93   94   91   84   76   72   71
    37.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   82   84   86   87   89   96  108  122  130  128  116  101   87   77   70   63
   58   56   59   64   69   73   76   79   82   84   83   80   74   67   60   55
   53   51   49   47   45   44   47   51   55   59   62   63   63   62   62   64
   67   69   69   68   67   69   74   81   86   89   90   89   88   88   88   89
   92   96  100  103  100   94   87   83   82
    35.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   94   95   94   89   84   86   96  111  122  125  118  108   98   92   85   77
   70   67   69   74   81   86   89   92   93   93   91   85   77   68   61   57
   55   53   51   48   45   44   46   51   56   61   64   66   66   66   66   67
   68   68   67   64   64   68   75   83   90   95   97   98   98   99   99  101
  103  107  112  115  113  108  100   95   94
    32.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
  109  109  104   94   81   75   80   93  107  114  113  109  106  104   98   90
   80   75   76   82   88   93   95   97   98   97   93   86   77   68   61   58
   57   56   55   51   48   47   49   54   59   63   67   69   70   70   68   67
   65   64   61   59   61   67   76   86   94   99  103  105  108  111  114  116
  119  123  128  130  129  123  116  110  109
    30.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
  127  127  121  106   85   69   66   75   88   98  103  106  110  112  108   98
   87   80   80   84   90   93   94   95   95   93   89   82   74   67   61   58
   58   59   59   57   54   52   54   58   63   66   68   71   72   70   67   63
   59   56   54   54   58   67   78   89   97  102  107  111  117  123  129  135
  139  143  147  149  147  141  133  127  127
  ...
  1                                                      END OF TEC MAP
```

Data begins 'START OF TEC MAP' and ends with 'END OF RMS MAP'. In order to not process header..

```
sed -n -i '/START OF TEC MAP/,/END OF RMS MAP/p'
```

I try getting 2nd line of the last five values which begins with 45.0-180.0 and ends with 25.0-180.0 for every loop. So it should be like that:

```
   2018     1     1     0     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
   ...
   45.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   54   56   54   50   46     
    42.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H       
   63   62   59   54   50
    40.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H       
   72   69   64   58   53
    37.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   80   74   67   60   55
    35.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   85   77   68   61   57
    32.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   86   77   68   61   58
    30.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
   82   74   67   61   58
  ...
  1                                                      END OF TEC MAP
```

Regexp is complex like my beginner.

- ^ at beginning with pattern
- [0-9] float numbers?
- $ at ending  \
- escape regexp character (LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by, "I try getting 2nd line of the last five values which begins with 45.0-180.0 until this for every loop." That sentence doesn't seem consistent with what you showed as your expected response?

Comment: Data considering this line 'LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H'. Skip this header line and get 2nd line of the last five values in the data.

Comment: And do you want to repeat for each data set enclosed in the START and END OF MAP blocks?

Comment: Yes and 'EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP'.

Comment: Done. Tell me what you think. I assumed that the whitespaces aren't important to you. Let me know if that assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following AWK should solve this problem:

```bash
awk '
  /(START|END|EPOCH) OF (TEC|RMS|CURRENT) MAP/
  $1 == "45.0-180.0" {p=1}
  $1 == "25.0-180.0" {p=0}
  p && $0 ~ "LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H" {
    print; getline; getline
    print $(NF-4)" "$(NF-3)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF
  }
' < FILE
```

Explanation:

- The first line always print lines matching the regex `/(START|END|EPOCH) OF (TEC|RMS|CURRENT) MAP/`. This will include all the headers you want to always include.
- The next two lines sets to true or false (1 or 0) a flag "p", depending on the contents of `$1`, the first field.
- `$0 ~ "LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H"` allows me to match the `/` character in an AWK regex, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789643/search-pattern-containing-forward-slash-using-awk) for more info on that syntax. Adding `p && $0 ~ "LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H" { ... }` says if p is true and the whole line matches the pattern, then do the steps inside the block `{ ... }`.
- Inside the block, I print that line, and then call [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) twice to read 2 more lines.
- Then print the 5th last, 4th last, 3rd last, 2nd last and last field relative to AWK's special [`$NF`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html) variable, which gives you the number of fields.

Testing:

```
▶ awk '
    /(START|END|EPOCH) OF (TEC|RMS|CURRENT) MAP/
    $1 == "45.0-180.0" {p=1}
    $1 == "25.0-180.0" {p=0}
    p && $0 ~ "LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H" {
      print; getline; getline
      print $(NF-4)" "$(NF-3)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF
    }
  ' < c1pg0010.18i
```

I get:

```
     1                                                      START OF TEC MAP
  2018     1     1     0     0     0                        EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP
    45.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
44 45 44 43 42
    42.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
53 54 54 52 51
    40.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
61 62 61 59 57
    37.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
67 66 65 63 61
    35.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
71 70 68 67 65
    32.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
75 72 71 71 69
    30.0-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
79 76 75 76 75
    27.5-180.0 180.0   5.0 450.0                            LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H
85 82 81 82 83
     1                                                      END OF TEC MAP
     2                                                      START OF TEC MAP
...
```

If you then need code to process all of the 31 files in the FTP directory, wrap your AWK in this Bash code:

```bash
for f in *.Z ; do
  gunzip $f
  decompressed=${f%.Z}
  awk '
    /(START|END|EPOCH) OF (TEC|RMS|CURRENT) MAP/
    $1 == "45.0-180.0" {p=1}
    $1 == "25.0-180.0" {p=0}
    p && $0 ~ "LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H" {
      print; getline; getline
      print $(NF-4)" "$(NF-3)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF
    }
  ' < $decompressed > $decompressed.edited
done
```

My assumption there is that you run this script from the directory containing all the data files with extension `.Z`.

Comment: I try understanding your code but result is not correct. Because it extracted all string "LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H". I just look for beginning with 45.0 and ending with 25.0.   There is no need to extract negative line such as -45.0 and "EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP" is vital important because I can understand values that belongs to which epoch. I mean it is not clear.

Comment: But your sample output shows that you are selecting other lines. And you haven't mentioned 25.0 until now?

Comment: I didn't explain myself very well in my opinion. Sorry for my English. "I try getting 2nd line of the last five values which begins with 45.0-180.0 and ends with 25.0-180.0 for every loop. So it should be like that:"

Comment: @GauSS, I have updated the code and answer based on your clarification here.

Comment: Output doesn't give line of '**START OF RMS MAP**' and '**END OF RMS MAP**'. Code should be like that?  `awk '
    /START OF TEC MAP/; /EPOCH OF CURRENT MAP/; /END OF TEC MAP/
    /START OF RMS MAP/; /EPOCH OF RMS MAP/; /END OF RMS MAP/
    $1 == "45.0-180.0" {p=1}
    $1 == "25.0-180.0" {p=0}
    p && $0~"LAT/LON1/LON2/DLON/H" {
      print; getline; getline
      print $(NF-4)" "$(NF-3)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF
    }
  ' `On the other hand, it is for one file, isn't it? However, I need to apply similiar code for 31 files.

Comment: @GauSS, I think you can do better than that using a regex, `/(START|END|EPOCH) OF (TEC|RMS|CURRENT) MAP/`. I guess you can figure out how that works. For processing 31 files, see my update to the answer.

Comment: It is time to learn and understand bash loop, sed, and awk. I can't believe that it is easy to solve problems via Linux. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome @GauSS. I suggest: learn the basics of Bash, learn the basics of Regex, and also have a look at an AWK tutorial, e.g. https://www.funtoo.org/Awk_by_Example,_Part_1 Sed is less important, because most of the time you can just use AWK. But it's also useful and not too hard.

Comment: By the way, I don't understand your code because it uncompressed file and remove Z file, doesn't it? And then? Also, what is '<'?

Comment: The `gunzip` command decompressed the file and removes the .Z extension, see `man gunzip`. The `<` is [IO redirection](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html). See also Bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) that I used to remove the .Z from the filename.

Comment: Why does output show in the terminal? I mean it may have written in text file or not? I am confused right now.

Comment: Yes, the script is writing output to the terminal. I don't believe you've told me  where you'd like the output written to? :)

Comment: My fault! When I try some code, I always break my text file. That's why I am scared of writing anything. Is it possible to write output to text file for every file or edit it in the same file for every files?

Comment: See my minor update to the Bash code. It now will write out a modified copy of $decompressed as $decompressed.edited.